How to use a whole directory in a test/binary built with bazel
We have a bazel_binary which iterates through all the subdirectories of a fixed directory, and parses the .json files in them, as follows. We want to use a directory iterator because this directory can have more subdirectories in future with new .json files in them.
for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("/system/artefacts")) {
  if (entry.is_directory()) {
    // find .json files and do stuff with them
  }
}

We are using bazel to build and run this binary, the bazel target looks like:
cc_binary(
    name = "dir_iterator",
    srcs = [
        "dir_iterator.cpp",
    ],
    data = [
        ":data",
    ],
    deps = [
        #...
    ],
)

filegroup(
    name = "data",
    srcs = glob([
        "system/artefacts", # does NOT work
    ]),
)

When we run this target with bazel run it fails with the following error:
t3-build-shell-5.0$ bazel run //utils:dir_iterator
INFO: Analyzed target //utils:dir_iterator (1 packages loaded, 8 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //utils:dir_iterator up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/utils/dir_iterator
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.082s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/utils/dir_iterator
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: directory iterator cannot open directory: No such file or directory [system/artifacts/]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: directory iterator cannot open directory: No such file or directory [system/artefacts/]

This is because bazel is not including the directory in question in the runtime environment.
So the question is: how can I include the directory in question with this bazel target, to get rid of this error?
Directory structure of bazel workspace
.
├── system
│   └── artefacts
│       ├── x
│       │   └── a.json
│       ├── y
│       │   └── a.json
│       └── z
│           └── a.json
└── util
    ├── BUILD
    └── dir_iterator.cpp


BUILD files can't access files outside their package (i.e. their directory and subdirectories (which aren't themselves packages, i.e. have a BUILD file)), so you'll need to create another BUILD file with the filegroup in a parent directory of the json file, and reference it in util/BUILD.
Also I believe /system/artefacts will be an absolute file path, which won't work, and should be a relative path (system/artefacts).
This worked for me:
$ tree
.
├── system
│   └── artefacts
│       ├── BUILD
│       ├── x
│       │   └── a.json
│       ├── y
│       │   └── a.json
│       └── z
│           └── a.json
├── util
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── dir_iterator.cpp
└── WORKSPACE

$ cat system/artefacts/BUILD 
filegroup(
  name = "artefacts",
  srcs = glob(["**/*.json"]),
  visibility = ["//util:__pkg__"],
)

$ cat util/BUILD 
cc_binary(
    name = "dir_iterator",
    srcs = [
        "dir_iterator.cpp",
    ],
    data = [
        "//system/artefacts:artefacts",
    ],
    deps = [
        #...
    ],
)

$ cat util/dir_iterator.cpp 
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("system/artefacts")) {
    if (entry.is_directory()) {
      std::cout << entry << "\n";
    }
  }
}

$ bazel run util/dir_iterator --copt=-std=c++17
INFO: Analyzed target //util:dir_iterator (2 packages loaded, 6 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //util:dir_iterator up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/util/dir_iterator
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.864s, Critical Path: 0.59s
INFO: 5 processes: 3 internal, 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/util/dir_iterator
"system/artefacts/z"
"system/artefacts/x"
"system/artefacts/y"

